# If $A,B\subset H$ are closed subspaces and $\operatorname{codim}(A+B)<\infty$ do we have $A+B$ closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A,B\subset H$ be two closed subspaces such that $\operatorname{codim}(A+B)<\infty $. I would be very surprised if it tuns out that $A+B$ is not necessarily closed. I've tried to use the closed graph theorem with the help of projections but without any success.

Comment: Seems difficult. I know a *relatively* simple example where $A+B$ is different from $H$ and dense (therefore not closed). Having seen mentioned that such a thing exists, I found that example, discovered later an exercise in Rudin's Functional Analysis which is nearly the same thing. This makes me doubt the existence of simpler examples. Do you know about this? I don't know the $Codim(A+B)$ ... but I guess it is 1 or infinite (due to its simple nature)

Comment: In the example you mentioned $\operatorname{codim}\left(A+B\right)=\infty$ @UlysseKeller